# WebException rethrow

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the following code:

```
    public static string Post(string requestUriString, string s)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webException);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When the program throws an exception, the try / catch block works correctly.

However when I try to rethrow the exception, the program crashes.

Comment: if you don't handle the exception anywhere then it's normal your app crashes. Don't rethrow it if you're not going to handle it? - for example return "" when an exception occurs or create a Response object that has a status and the body, set the status = failed when an exception occurs.

Comment: Then add a try/catch there and handle the exception, not handling/catching an exception will exit your application. Using exceptions this way isn't really good design, don't use exceptions for flow control. the Post method is responsible for returning a "Response" - so ideally your handling would be in that class.

Comment: It should crash as you don't handle exception re-throw, you need to `try` `catch` in `Main()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should crash as you don't handle exception re-throw, you need to `try` `catch` in `Main()` method as below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Post("https://stackoverflow.com/", "test");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //  Handle exception re-throw,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var response = Post(...);

        if(response.Status == "success") {
            //ok
        } else {
            //request failed
        }
    }

    public static string Post(string requestUriString, string s) {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        try {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var body = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return new Response("success", body);
        } catch (WebException webException) {
            Console.WriteLine(webException);
            return new Response("failed", "");
        }
    }

    class Response {
        public string Status { get; private set; }
        public string Body { get; private set; }

        public Response(string status, string response) {
            Status = status;
            Body = response;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs & app size you could make the status an enum based on the http response code(200/404/500...) etc and add some more handling because the sample I posted isn't something you should use for something bigger or production critical.

You mentioned it's a console app, if it's just something that does a single request and nothing else this should do the job just fine.

Comment: I just want to rethrow the exception to handle it in the Main() method...

Comment: You have done that @YannickAllegre. The bug in your code is in the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this code :

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace Botnet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Post("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", "thing1=hello&thing2=world"));
            }
            catch (WebException webException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(webException);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static string Post(string requestUriString, string s)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (WebException webException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(webException);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will modify previous answer a little bit.

```
class Response<T> {
        public HttpStatusCode Status { get; private set; }
        public T Body { get; private set; }
        public bool Success { get; private set; }
        public string Reason {get; private set; }

        public Response(T body) {
            Success = true;
            Body = body;
            HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        }

        public Response(string reason)
        {
            Reason = reason;
            Success = false;
            Status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        public Response( string reason, HttpStatusCode status)
        {
            Reason = reason;
            Status = status;
            Success = false;
        }
    }
```

This is more generic solution.